# Facebook Login - Get User Data

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I'm building an app on iOS using Parse as a backend.

Doing so I use the Parse Facebook SDK in order first to link Facebook to my Parse User and then to query his data and save them.

**The Problem is:** sometimes I don't get some of the info like eMail (userData[@"email"] is nil), first_name,name .., or the Profile Pic doesn't download.

Not all the time (quite rare actually), and impossible to reliably replicate the issue so I can solve it. And it's often only one missing field not all.

So I got holes in my Database (not cool when it is the user's email address: ***my main concern***)

Here is how I wrote my methods (i edited most of the if(error) management to make it shorter).

Any ideas ?

Thank you guys !

```
    NSArray *permissionsArray = @[@"public_profile",@"email", @"user_friends"];

    [PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];

    // Login PFUser using Facebook
    [PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (user.isNew) {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook signed up and logged in!");
            [self fbData:self];

        } else {
            NSLog(@"User with facebook logged in!");
            [self fbDataAlreadyLog:self];
        }
    }];
```

Then I call my "fbData" function in order to fill in the user data into Parse:

```
-(IBAction)fbData:(id)sender{

[PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebook];
FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForMe];

// Send request to Facebook
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *userCloud, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        // result is a dictionary with the user's Facebook data
        NSDictionary *userData = userCloud;

        NSString *facebookID = userData[@"id"];

        NSURL *pictureURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1", facebookID]];

        PFUser *user = [PFUser currentUser];
        if (userData[@"name"]) {
            user[@"name"] = userData[@"name"];
        }
        if (userData[@"first_name"]) {
            user[@"first_name"] = userData[@"first_name"];
        }
        if (userData[@"last_name"]) {
            user[@"last_name"] = userData[@"last_name"];
        }
        if (userData[@"id"]) {
            user[@"fbID"] = userData[@"id"];
        }
        if (userData[@"gender"]) {
            user[@"gender"] = userData[@"gender"];
        }
        if (userData[@"email"]) {
            user.email = userData[@"email"];
            user.username = userData[@"email"];
        }
        if (userData[@"age_range"]) {
            user[@"age_range"] = userData[@"age_range"];
        }

        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        [manager downloadImageWithURL:pictureURL
                              options:0
                             progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize)
         {
             // progression tracking code
         }
                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished,NSURL *imageURL)
         {
             if (image)
             {
                 // do something with image
                 NSData *imageNSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
                 PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"profilePic" data:imageNSData];
                 user[@"image"] = imageFile;

                 [user saveInBackgroundWithBlock];

                 //Once the Save Block is done I managed a few more thing before moving on to the next ViewController

             }
         }];
   }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"user_about_me", @"user_relationships", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];
```