# Facebook SDK not giving user Email id

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Facebook sdk not returning user email_id in json object. Tried so many methods but found no solution. Things which were required for facebook implementation

1-change other linker flag to (-ObjC)

2-make a url Scheme

3-add facebook_id and name in project pList

4-using a UIView in storyboard and assigning FBLoginView class to it.

5-allocating and initing and giving read permissions.

here's the code for giving permission :

```
_fbLoginVIew =[[FBLoginView alloc] init];

_fbLoginVIew.delegate=self;

_fbLoginVIew.readPermissions= @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

and delegate method that returns the user information :

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{

    defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setValue:user.name forKey:@"name"];

    [defaults setValue:[user objectforkey:@"email"] forkey:@"email"];

    [defaults synchronize];

}
```

but after implementing all these things and searching for solution i am still stuck on my problem.
please help in solving this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please read this on how to ask a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i think it is now easier to read. would you please give me solution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27227061/facebook-login-get-user-data/27227353#27227353 look at this

Comment: _fbLoginVIew =[[FBLoginView alloc] init];
_fbLoginVIew.delegate=self;
    _fbLoginVIew.readPermissions= @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

Comment: see my edited answer.. i 've added code snippet.- unheiling

Answer (score 1):

This problem is due to user restrict his/her email to shown up in timeline

so you can't access for that when you only allowing permission for this

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's very simple. You should just give proper `readPermissions` when initializing the `FBLoginView` like:

```
FBLoginView *loginView = 
    [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithReadPermissions:
        @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]];
```

or, if you are creating login view on interface builder:

```
self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];
```

in `viewDidLoad` of your view controller.

For future help on Facebook, please read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.2)

Good Luck!

Comment: Actually, i am giving permissions like this. But found no success. is there any possibility that i 've missed something for SDK implementation.???

Comment: if the `- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user` method is being called then I think everything is alright with your Facebook setup. Did you try to `NSLog` the fetched user info?

Comment: yes i did.. and the result was "NULL" is console. Even i recreated my project id on store and synthesized the project, thinking that it may help. but failed...